# After Lubuntu install, can't connect to WiFi, can connect to Ethernet

Tags: lubuntu, network-manager

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome
```

followed by:

```
nm-applet
```

but it gave me:

```
dbind-WARNING **: 21:03:15.214: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files.
```

What's going wrong?

(my PC originally had Windows 8 on it & I dual-booted it with Lubuntu Bionic Beaver)

The previous output for:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome
```

was as follows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
network-manager-gnome is already the newest version (1.8.10-2ubuntu3).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libglade2-0 python-bluez python-cairo python-glade2 python-gobject-2
  python-gtk2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 460 not to upgrade.
```

After using:

```
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

The current output for:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome
```

is as follows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
network-manager-gnome is already the newest version (1.8.10-2ubuntu3).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libglade2-0 libllvm6.0 python-bluez python-cairo python-glade2
  python-gobject-2 python-gtk2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

All anonymous results of "wireless-info.txt" are at https://pastebin.com/BG4pS3ke

Comment: Nm-applet is not a package to install. Also, both the network manager and nm-applet are preinstalled.

Comment: Then why can't I connect to wireless networks? Only wired networks are working.

Comment: I don't know why, but if you provide [more info](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos), perhaps I will. Also, what was the output of `sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome`? You forgot to post it.

Comment: Let me go through the More Info & XY Problem links. I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: First you need to fix "460 not to upgrade", then after that fix the wireless. Please edit your question above to include the complete output of `sudo apt full-upgrade`

Comment: Please see https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/197910 collect the resulting info and make it available by pasting to a public text hosting site such as http://pastebin.com or https://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: I've now added the results of Wireless Info Script.

Comment: You have a Broadcom `BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365]` which usually needs a driver installed: `sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source`. There is also a preinstalled program called "Additional Drivers" to do it for you. Hope it helps.